# printf %.4f for IP?

Tags: php

I would like to print an IP in fixed way.. example

12.12.1.0

would tured to

012.012.001.000

what's the best method do it ?

`printf("%.4f.%.4f.%.4f.%.4f",$ip);` ?

Comment: Ew, no-one reads IPs like this. Besides, leading zeroes are often used to signify octal values, which these are not. Please don't do this.

Comment: Zeroes signify octal values even in this particular context: [`inet_aton`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With zero padding:

```
$ip = "12.12.1.0";

vprintf("%03d.%03d.%03d.%03d", explode('.', $ip));
```